# How do we interact with the Direct Message entity?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-community

In communities there are the concept of direct messages:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable_direct_messages.htm&type=5

In the 'limitations' section of them it describes ways in which we can interact with them:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_direct_messages_considerations.htm&type=5

It describes them as the following:

> Under the hood, direct messages are a special implementation of feed
>   posts and comments parented to a direct message entity.

Has anyone had any luck either creating these records, or firing the 'e.force:createRecord' event with reference too them?

Comment: I am really unsure, but typically anything related to chatter (FeedItem, Feed*) cannot be created directly via API.

Comment: On the 'limitations' page it does seem to imply that we can create these records: 

"In the community UI, direct messages display only to the participants in the conversation. However, Apex code runs in system mode, which means that the permissions of the current user aren’t taken into account. This limitation has implications for pages that use Apex and Visualforce."

Comment: Well did you try with the Lightning Data Service or the 'e.force:createRecord' event?

Comment: i would but i dont know what type of record i need to create or what parameters it would take.

Comment: From the documentation you linked, I would assume they are a variation of FeedItem                        https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm

Comment: I've found that the 'new message' component is called 'forceChatter:newMessageButton' but i cant instantiate it either. is there a way to instantiate these standard salesforce components?

Comment: I also tried the 'e.force:createRecord' on the FeedItem and it didnt work

Comment: Look into the direction of existing lightning components maybe? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_forceChatter_publisher.htm                  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_forceChatter_feed.htm   Those are the only ones I could find though :( Sorry